# Yii conditional relation

Tags: activerecord, yii, foreign-keys

I have a `chat` table with fields

```
 admin TINYINT
 owner_id INTEGER
```

The goal is to have two relations in Yii:

```
'admin'=>array(
    self::BELONGS_TO, 'Admin', 'owner_id',
    'condition'=>'admin=1',
 ),

'user'=>array(
    self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'owner_id',
    'condition'=>'admin=0',
 ),
```

However, I got `General error: 1 no such column: admin`, and could manage only by adding `all_ones` and `all_zeros` columns to Admin table, so I could write

```
        'admin'=>array(
            self::BELONGS_TO, 'Admin', array('owner_id' => 'id', 'admin' => 'all_ones'),
        ),


        'user'=>array(
            self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', array('owner_id' => 'id', 'admin' => 'all_zeros'),
        ),
```

What is the way I could implement that without using such a hacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1:

Put your relations on User model (because the relation condition does filter the related model, not the model the relation is defined on)

```
//On the User model:

'chatsAdmin'=>array(
   self::HAS_MANY, 'Chat', 'owner_id',
   'condition'=>'admin=1',
),
'chats'=>array(
   self::HAS_MANY, 'Chat', 'owner_id',
   'condition'=>'admin=0',
),
```

Solution 2:

Use finder to get a filtered set of Chats (or DataProvider)

```
//relation on chat (without condition!)
'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'owner_id')

//finder on chat model, will return ALL (use CActiveDataProvider if you need paging..)

Chat::model()->with('user')->findAll('user.admin=:admin', array(':admin'=>1))
```