# How to make a conditional active record relationship in Yii

Tags: yii, yii2

I have Post, Comment, and User in a Yii api. When a Post is queried, the result should be the Post data, the User that made the Post, and any Comments for that Post, and the User who made the Comment with complete User data.

The Comment table includes a `created_by` field which is the `user_id` in the User table.

To get a single Post, here is the controller:

```
public function actionView($id){
    $post = Post::find()
        ->innerJoinWith('user')
        ->joinWith('comments')
        ->where(['{{post}}.id' => $id])
        ->asArray()
        ->one();
    return $post;
}
```

This returns a single Post by id, and any Comments.

To get all posts:

```
public function actionIndex(){
   $posts = Post::find()
     ->joinWith('user', $eager)
     ->joinWith('comments', $eager)
     ->orderBy('updated_at DESC')
     ->limit(self::MAX_ROWS)
     ->asArray()
     ->all();
  return $posts;
}
```

In the Post model, the Comment relationship is set like this:

```
public function getComments()
{
    return $this
      ->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['object_id' => 'id']);
}
```

So this returns Comments if thre are any, but not the complete User data for each User who commented. So I added this to `getComments()`

```
      ->joinWith('user u2','u2.id = comment.created_by')
```

Which does return the User data along with the Comment,  EXCEPT.... now `actionIndex()` only returns Posts that have Comments.

I reviewed [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635756/yii-conditional-relation) but didn't find a solution. How do I conditionally include the `joinWith` only for Posts with Comments?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use `->with()` instead of `joinWith()`:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $posts = Post::find()
        ->with('user')
        ->with('comments')
        ->orderBy('updated_at DESC')
        ->limit(self::MAX_ROWS)
        ->asArray()
        ->all();

    return $posts;
}
```

This way, you just use the relationship you already should have declared in your `Post` model class. After that, also add `->with()` to your `comments` relationship declaration in your `Post` model class:

```
public function getComments() {
    return $this
        ->hasMany(Comment::className(), [
            'object_id' => 'id',
        ])
        ->with('user');
}
```

This way, you should get all the posts, the user and comments with their own users.